# Merging MP3 results in wrong duration time (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, mp3

I`m get some strange behavior from my AVAudioPlayer after merging multiple MP3's files, all the time I call "[AVAudioPlayer setCurrentTime: anyValueAfter260]" the current time is always set to 260, that's because the MP3 duration info is wrong. Anyone have some clue how can I replace that info on the MP3 or if is something wrong with my co
Here is my merge code:

```
NSMutableData *original =  original = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
for (int i=0; i< [self.filesPath count]; i++) {
    NSString *fileName = [self.filesPath objectAtIndex:i];
    NSMutableData *part=[NSMutableData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName]];
    [original appendData:part];
}

if(original!=nil){
    [original writeToURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString: self.finalPath ]  atomically:YES];
}
```

**Screenshot's**

File merged without problems on the left and file merged with wrong duration on the right

http://oi44.tinypic.com/9pm07c.jpg

MP3 with wrong duration on iTunes

http://oi43.tinypic.com/vcsy2t.jpg

The most strange thing is that this issue doesn't occur all the time, in some cases the final file show's the correct time...

Answer (score 1):

MP3 duration is not an easy thing to determine. If you **KNOW** that the file is CBR (constant bit-rate), it's just a matter of figuring out how large the first mp3 data frame is, and then it's simple math:

```
length of song = length of file
                 ----------------- * 0.028  
                 size of 1st frame
```

where every MP3 frame has a playback duration of 0.028 seconds. But if the file is VBR-encoded (variable bit-rate), this math falls apart. You'll have "long" frames and "short" frames. The only way to determine playback length of a VBR file is to scan the ENTIRE file, count how many frames there are, and then repeat the math:

```
length of song = number of frames * 0.028 seconds per frame
```

Given you're getting different playback lengths, you're likely combining MP3s with different bitrates and/or VBR-encoded files. The cases where you DO get the correct playback time, it's likely a CBR file, with the same bitrate used for each of the original component files.

Comment: But the problem here is why the AVAudioPlayer get this strange duration time, I already know the right duration of my generated file, but I can't set this on AVAudioPlayer (or I don't know how to set it)